# Regex that gets a comma followed by a number except at the beginning

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with numbers followed by a colon symbol and some text, separated by comma, like this:

```
2534:MULTIPLE TEST 10000 - CLONE,2533:RTD EMAIL PT01-08 SEND1 PW03
```

What I need is a string that get the numbers separated by comma. Like this:

```
2534,2533
```

I tried this, but it doesn't get the first number because it doesn't start with comma:

```
,[^:]*
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `s.replace(/:[^,]*/g, '')`? See https://regex101.com/r/AKHnhv/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const regex = /(\d)+(?=\:)/gm;
const str = `  2534:MULTIPLE TEST 10000 - CLONE,2533:RTD EMAIL PT01-08 SEND1 PW03`;
let strings = str.match(regex)
console.log(strings.join())
```

Comment: @dalamar it might be possible that there are no number in the String. please make you add to check if `strings` are present before joining the array

Comment: I check it before lauch the regex. If the string is empty I do nothing, otherwise, the string allways has numbers

Comment: well make sure string always has number, but if you get a string that don't have the numbers, or the strings which do not satisfy the regex pattern, then regex will return null, and if you try to write .join() on null then application will get crash!!!

Answer (score 0):

Define your format better: you have comma-separated strings (`2534:MULTIPLE TEST 10000 - CLONE` and `2533:RTD EMAIL PT01-08 SEND1 PW03`), so first separate those out:

```
const str = `2534:MULTIPLE TEST 10000 - CLONE,2533:RTD EMAIL PT01-08 SEND1 PW03`;
const parts = str.split(",");
```

Now, each part is a `number:string` pair. Split them, and keep only the first part (the number):

```
const numbers = parts.map(part=>part.split(":")[0]);
```

Done. No regex needed.

Comment: why `const`? it won't be a constant for sure

Comment: @FlashThunder You're not gonna be re-assigning it, are you? Then it's a `const`.

Comment: I think that he doesn't want to do that with only one line, so it will probably in some loop.